# Difference between content pane and layout in swing?

Tags: java, swing

Anyone explain to me the difference between content pane and layout with by example. Give code example where exactly need of content pane (or) layout.

What is the difference between these, and in what circumstances should you use one rather than the others?

Comment: *"Give code example.."*  Give cash.  (SO is not your personal tutor, nor a code generation machine).

Answer (score 4):

There is no comparison between `content pane` and `layout`; they are two distinct entities.

- [Content Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) :

  The default content pane is a simple intermediate container that inherits from JComponent, and that uses a BorderLayout as its layout manager.
- [Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

  It is used to place `components` on the `parent container`. These are basically the set of constraints, which establish the position of a given component on the parent container.

They both are used as you make a Swing Application. As when you write

```
frame.add(childComponent);
```

the `childComponent` is actually added to the content pane. Three methods, `add(...)`, `remove(...)` and `setLayout(...)`, are overridden for `content pane`.